# How to select items in a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I wrote a custom control to displays items from an ItemsSource at calculated positions.

**Generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:MyControls.Control">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control:MyControl}">
                    <Border x:Name="DrawingArea"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"                            
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ClipToBounds="true" />                            
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>     
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MyControl.cs**

```
public class MyControl : MultiSelector, INotifyPropertyChanged    
{
    private bool _layoutHandlingDone = false;
    private Border _drawingArea;
    private Border DrawingArea
    {
        get { return _drawingArea ?? (_drawingArea = (Border) Template.FindName("DrawingArea", this)); }
    }

    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size aviableSize) { ... }       
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) { ... }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        if (Template != null && _layoutHandlingDone == false)
        {
            _layoutHandlingDone = true;
            ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += (sender, args) =>
                                                        {
                                                            if(ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
                                                                InvalidateMeasure();
                                                        };
            DrawingArea.SizeChanged += (sender, args) => UpdateLayout();
        }
    }   
}
```

Layouting and drawing the items works very well. Now I want the items to be selectable. For this I derived my control form MultiSelector, but it seems that this isn't enough.

What functionality does the MultiSelector provide and how should I use it in my control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suggest to separate things here. Managing a collection of items and arranging them in a container control are two distinct concerns, and ItemsControl provides support for both.

Instead of overriding MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride, you should write your specialized [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) class (and override MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride there) and use that class in the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) template of your ItemsControl.

You could then easily derive from ListBox instead of MultiSelector and would get all the selection functionality for free.

Comment: Deriving form ListBox did it. Thanks. But did I get you right: I can derive from Panel instead of ListBox. Put MyPanel into the ItemsPanel property of ItmesControl, a ListBox or what ever is selectable. And would get the same functionality?

Comment: Exactly. That's what the `ItemsPanel` property was designed for. Use a ListBox with a specialized Panel. I do this for example to arrange items on a map control at geographic locations. The map items are managed by a standard ListBox, but the ItemsPanel template defines a specialized "MapPanel" that does all the necessary calculations for actually arranging the items.